# How to get a list of all external links

Tags: links

We want to move from http to https. Therefore we need a list of all external links in order to determine which ones have to be changes if external content is embedded. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Solution 1. SPE

I recommend using [Sitecore Powershell Extensions](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_PowerShell_console.aspx) for that.

Example code snippet:

```powershell
$fields = "Content", "Title"
$startPath = "/sitecore/content/Playground/Playground/int/Home"
$phrase = "http"

function Item-Report($i){
    $fields | % {
        if($i.Fields[$_] -ne $null -and $i.Fields[$_].Value.Contains($phrase) -eq $true){
            Write-Host $i.Paths.Path  "[" $_ "]"
        }        
    }
}

Get-ChildItem -Path $startPath -Recurse | % { Item-Report $_ }
```

- `$fields` - defines list of fields that should be checked.
- `$startPath` - this is start path. Root of all items you want to check
- `$phrase` - text you want to search in all fields

If needed you can use Regex instead of basic `Contains` (note that url can be **http** or **https**), this is just an example code snippet.

**Pros:**

You can invoke `Replace`, editing each field so you don't have to do it manually.

**Cons:**

You need to install additional module if you haven't it already

#### Solution 2. SQL

You can try to get report using **SQL Queries**.

Example:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1000 [Id]
    ,[ItemId]
    ,[FieldId]
    ,[Value]
    ,[Created]
    ,[Updated]
    ,[DAC_Index]
FROM [sxa_sitecore_master].[dbo].[VersionedFields]
WHERE FieldId in ('8DBAF611-51C6-4A44-A0DB-92C3DC6DDAC9', '{D81F4C5A-71D0-497E-9612-CFC960165412}') 
AND Value LIKE '%http%'
```

Depending how you store your data you should check other fields as well.

- `[sxa_sitecore_master].[dbo].[SharedFields]`
- `[sxa_sitecore_master].[dbo].[UnversionedFields]`

**Pros:**

Very fast, no additional modules needed.

**Cons:**

You can easily get a report but writing an `UPDATE` command could be hard and risky. I would not do it.

Comment: Thanks for the script. How can I get the values for each language of the field?

Comment: @thomas-isler
You will find an answer for your question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190603/get-field-value-in-other-language.